# Перекодировка текста в Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

С помощью `pysnmp` получаю Hex-String следующего вида:

```
# snmpwalk -v2c -c my-community my-ip 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.10
iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.10 = Hex-STRING: 80 A4 A0 AF E2 A5 E0 20 AC A0 A3 A8 E1 E2 E0 A0
AB EC AD AE A9 20 E1 A5 E2 A8 20 A2 A8 E0 E2 E3
A0 AB EC AD AE A9 20 AC A0 E8 A8 AD EB 20 28 8C
A0 A9 AA E0 AE E1 AE E4 E2 29 00
```

Затем с помощью **value.prettyPrint()[2:]** получаю вот это:

```
0x80a4a0afe2a5e020aca0a3a8e1e2e0a0abecadaea920e1a5e2a820a2a8e0e2e3a0abecadaea920aca0e8a8adeb20288ca0a9aae0aee1aee4e22900
```

Путем череды перекодировок, получаю на выходе строку

```
val = str(binascii.unhexlify( value.prettyPrint()[2:]).decode('cp1251').encode('utf8').decode('utf8'))
print(val)

Ђ¤ ЇвҐа ¬ ЈЁбва «м­®© бҐвЁ ўЁавг «м­®© ¬ иЁ­л (Њ ©Єа®б®дв)
```

Я уже пару часов бьюсь в поисковик, пытаясь найти решение, но все что я находил для меня не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = bytes.fromhex('80A4A0AFE2A5E020ACA0A3A8E1E2E0A0ABECADAEA920E1A5E2A820A2A8E0E2E3A0ABECADAEA920ACA0E8A8ADEB20288CA0A9AAE0AEE1AEE4E22900')
print(d.decode('cp866'))
```

> Адаптер магистральной сети виртуальной машины (Майкрософт)

Не знаю, какого типа значение возвращает `prettyPrint()`, но если это массив байт, не надо никакого `unhexlify`

```
print(value.prettyPrint()[2:].decode('cp866'))
```

если же строка, то как в примере, использовать `fromhex`